# Checking for existing entity before creating a new one

Tags: core-data

How do I check if an entity already exists before creating a new one with the same attributes? Or is CoreData already clever enough not create the entity?

Example, I have an entity Employee with attributes name and id. Now the user creates a new Employee through a dialog screen, but this Employee already exits, based on the id (there could be employees with the same name).  I guess could create a fetch request, but where do I put that code, do I need to make a class for Employee to do this?

edit: After postng my question, I found this page: http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxiii-itunes-ifying-core-data-app  Would that be a way to do this? Seems like if I have more entities, that I'm duplicating a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data will let you create managed objects which are identical in all but their objectID.

The simplest solution would be to disallow duplicate employee names. When the user enters a new employee, they will trigger an event via the keyboard or mouse. In your action method for this event, you will first validate the user's entry by checking whether the name they have entered matches an existing name. The link you cite gives an example of a fetch request that you could use, although you might want to investigate how to fetch just the count of matching objects, which would be more efficient. If there's a match, you display an alert.

If you really want to allow duplicate names, you can rely on the CoreData-assigned objectID to differentiate entries. But the user won't know what that ID is. So you would still need to check for a name match and display a confirmation dialog asking the user whether they really intend to create a separate employee entry with the same name.

Comment: thanks - I'll go ahead and implement the code from that link, and will look into your suggestion. Maybe I'll put it in a category, so I can use it for all my entities.